# Is it bad for SEO to forward multiple top level domains to just one domain?

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search

For example, I registered `myName.com` and I also registered the `.net`, `.info`, and `.org` extensions for `myName`. I'm wondering if it will hurt my SEO to forward these other TLDs to `myName.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't hurt, but it won't help either.

This is a very common practice.

The only benefit I can think of is by not letting anyone else use those names.

Comment: Correct, here's a related video from Matt Cutts: [Is the same content posted under different TLDs a problem?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo). Also be sure to use 301 redirects.

Answer (score 1):

If you will serve the same content on each of the domains it will definitely help your SEO since when redirecting using 301 redirects (as the previous answers comment states), you avoid having duplicate content issues.